# Spring RESTful Token Web Service Review

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have been going square trying to implement a new RESTful web service using Spring.IO. I've worked through perhaps 30 different online examples that suppose to provide this example but none of them worked 'out of the box'.

A further complication is that 95% of examples use XML configuration exclusively, which in my personal opinion is not as readable as a pure java configuration.

After a great many hours I have managed to cobble together something that 'works' but I would very much be interested in feedback as to my particular implementation. Specifically:

1. Assuming the client authorisation token is not compromised is my implementation secure.
2. I was unable to correctly AutoWire the `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter` class in `WebSecurityConfig` due to the constructor requiring an AuthenticationManager. If there is a way to do this that would help clean things up a little.

The main application class:

```
@ComponentScan({"webservice"})
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `WebSecurityConfig` class (AFAIK this does the majority of the job previously performed by the XML):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authenticationTokenProcessingFilter;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        authenticationTokenProcessingFilter = 
            new AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(authenticationManager());

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}
```

The `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter` which performs the token authentication on client connect:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    AuthenticationManager authManager;

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        this.authManager = authManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String[]> parms = request.getParameterMap();

        if(parms.containsKey("authToken")) {
            String token = parms.get("authToken")[0];

            // Validate the token
            User user = TokenUtils.getUserFromToken(token);

            // If we managed to get a user we can finish the authentication
            if (user!=null) {
                //Add a default authority for all users
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList();
                grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

                // build an Authentication object with the user's info
                AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication = 
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, token, grantedAuths);

                // set the authentication into the SecurityContext
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);         
            }
        }

        // continue thru the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The `TokenUtils` class used by `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter`:

```
public class TokenUtils {

    /**
     * Get an authorisation token for the provided userId
     * 
     * @param userId
     * @return 
     */
    public static String getToken(long userId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet!");
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to get a user for the provided token
     * 
     * @param token
     * @return User if found, otherwise null
     */
    public static User getUserFromToken(String token) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet!");
    } 
}
```

The `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint`, which returns a 403 if the user was not successfully authenticated:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized: Authentication token was either missing or invalid." );
    }
}
```

An finally my web service entry points:

```
@RestController
public class EntryPoints {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=true) String password) {

        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password);

        //Authenticate the user using the provided credentials

        //If succesfull return authentication token
        //return new LoginResponse(token);

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet!");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public AccountResponse account(@RequestParam(value="accountId", required=true) long accountId) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        //Return the request account information

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably better for Code Review; I don't see a specific question. Also, have a look at Spring Session.

Comment: @chrylis - Thanks for the comment, my specific questions are at the top, numbered 1 and 2.

Comment: Looks to me like you're giving all users admin rights -- that can't be very secure

Comment: Does this work? Like everyone, I'm flaky with spring security, but we have something similar to you, but with ldap and sso, but our rest controller has @PreAuthorize on the secured methods...

Comment: @EngineerDollery - My understanding is that the user role is just a string that you can match too at a later stage. At the moment I do not have any "@Secured" endpoints so it's actually redundant. It does seem to run well, sans the minor missing implementation sections.